Updating Azure Container app Startup Probe using CLI is not working
I'm trying to update Azure container app startup probe using Az Cli. Below is the command
az containerapp update --name $containerAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --set `
  properties.template.containers.probes.type="Startup" `
  properties.template.containers.probes.httpGet.path="/" `
  properties.template.containers.probes.httpGet.port=80 `
  properties.template.containers.probes.initialDelaySeconds=20 `
  properties.template.containers.probes.periodSeconds=3

After running the above command, when we query the container app for changes
az containerapp show --name $containerAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --query "properties.template.containers[0].probes"

we still see the old configuration for the startup probes (even after allowing the revision to be up and running).
Could you please suggest is there any way we can update the probes in Azure Container apps using cli.
Thanks in advance.

Hi @Madhu, You can use the command to update Azure container app prob settings az containerapp update --name "venkat-container" --resource-group "Venkat-RG" --set properties.template.containers.probes.type="Startup" properties.template.containers.probes.httpGet.path="/" properties.template.containers.probes.httpGet.port=80 properties.template.containers.probes.initialDelaySeconds=20 properties.template.containers.probes.periodSeconds=3

Check the updated configuration using the commandaz containerapp show --name "venkat-container" --resource-group "Venkat-RG" --query "properties.template.containers[0]" Here is the result

Here is the command to update Azure Container App probe settings using Azure CLI.

Note: Ensure that the container app is running. If it is not running, please start the application


az containerapp update --name "venkat-container" --resource-group "Venkat-RG" --set properties.template.containers.probes.type="Startup" properties.template.containers.probes.httpGet.path="/" properties.template.containers.probes.httpGet.port=80 properties.template.containers.probes.initialDelaySeconds=20 properties.template.containers.probes.periodSeconds=3

Output
az containerapp show --name "venkat-container" --resource-group "Venkat-RG" --query "properties.template.containers[0]"

After running the command, the Azure Container App probe settings have been updated with given values.


Thanks for your response. My concern is about updating the probes. I tried the command mentioned above, but still I don't see the probe values are getting updated

Use these command to check the updated configuration az containerapp show --name "venkat-container" --resource-group "Venkat-RG" --query "properties.template.containers[0]"

PS C:\Users\dev> az containerapp show --name 'test-app' --resource-group 'dtest-rg' --query "properties.template.containers[0].probes"
The behavior of this command has been altered by the following extension: containerapp
[
{
"httpGet": {
"port": 80,
"scheme": "HTTP"
},
"type": "Liveness"
},
{
"httpGet": {
"port": 80,
"scheme": "HTTP"
},
"type": "Readiness"
},
{
"tcpSocket": {
"port": 80
},
"type": "Startup"
}
]

The command you executed to show the probe settings of the Azure Container App named 'test-app' in the resource group 'dtest-rg' was successful,The output indicates that you have three different probes configured for your container app: a liveness probe, a readiness probe, and a startup probe

Yes that's true, My concern is I'm updating the initialDelaySeconds for statup probe, but the update is not happening. For some reason I don't see the updated value neither in portal nor in the command output.

Can you please share the command you're using and output screenshot.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
